# SQL Statement with OR never finishes executing, freezes SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have an SQL statement

```
SELECT dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID,
[IP_ADDR1_TEXT],dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_DOMAIN_NAME, [ID],dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION
FROM sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], IDENTITY_MAP, SEM_CLIENT,dbo.SEM_AGENT
WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID and dbo.IDENTITY_MAP.ID = dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID
and dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID
AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
AND NAME = 'My Company\Default Group'
OR NAME = 'My Company\Bronx'
order by [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
```

That executed indefinitely and even freezes the SQL server when I tried to copy and paste this code.

If I remove the

```
OR NAME = 'My Company\Bronx'
```

then the the SQL statement executes just fine

We are using SQL Server 2008

Thank you

Comment: I assume you need parentheses around the 2 conditions: `AND (NAME = 'My Company\Default Group' OR NAME = 'My Company\Bronx')`

Comment: Because you get something like cross join. See the @NickyvV's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this whole problem becomes a lot clearer if you write ANSI-Compliant T-SQL. So rather than have your able join conditions in the WHERE clause, you have something like:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME
,   dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID
,   [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
,   dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_DOMAIN_NAME
,   [ID]
,   dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION
FROM
sem_computer AS COM
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER] AS V
ON
COM.COMPUTER_ID = V.COMPUTER_ID
INNER JOIN
dbo.SEM_CLIENT AS CLI
ON
COM.COMPUTER_ID = CLI.COMPUTER_ID
INNER JOIN
dbo.SEM_AGENT AS AGT
ON
COM.COMPUTER_ID = AGT.COMPUTER_ID
INNER JOIN
IDENTITY_MAP AS IM
ON
CLI.GROUP_ID = IM.ID
```

...

Then your WHERE clause does what it is designed to do, which is filter your data. This becomes, as suggested earlier

```
WHERE
NAME IN('My Company\Default Group','My Company\Bronx')
```

The performance problem you had was, as pointed out, you were getting a cross join of all tables. But I think you would have noticed this if you write your joins in an ANSI compliant way.

I hope that helps.

Ash

Comment: I removed the aliases because they were giving errors such as "The multi-part identifier "dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME" could not be bound."

Answer (score 1):

> OR NAME IN('My Company\Default Group','My Company\Bronx')

Should work.

When you have the AND NAME = 'My Company\Default Group'
OR NAME = 'My Company\Bronx' not in parentheses or using an IN clause, it means that it will get everything where the OR condition is satisfied, ignoring all of the other conditions.